# Have Raj Chetty's Opportunity Atlas stats changed or been recalculated since early 2019?

Tags: statistics, inequality

During a talk at Google, Raj Chetty said "Fruitvale, in Oakland ... here you see that for black men growing up in low income families in Fruitvale, the average income in adulthood is **5,600 dollars**" (see https://youtu.be/X2YzxpWKKz4?t=844).

However, at https://www.opportunityatlas.org/, I appear to see **15,000 dollars** for the same statistic (note the selections for parent income, child race and child gender at the top right of the screenshot):

[image: Opportunity Atlas Screenshot]

Have the numbers changed?  Has the methodology been adjusted?  What explains the difference?

I noticed a similar discrepancy related to incarceration rates:

[image: Second Opportunity Atlas Screenshot (Incarceration Rates)]

During the Google presentation, Raj Chetty says "**43%** of the black men who grew up in this particular neighborhood [Fruitvale] are incarcerated ... on the date of the 2010 census", but Opportunity Atlas (viewed in December 2019) gives **17%** for the same incarceration rate statistic.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think it had been recalculated becouse his plans for the American drean is still on sight,to me he has dispel the myth for of social mobility than anyone else
and that of fruitvale in Oakland the income is highly disappointing for the black people which as such other might think is kind of a racist thing forgive me but is something to look at